# why do I get the error " Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled" when training with mixed precision?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to training my model with mixed precision on tensorflow, I followed the code here https://github.com/khcs/fp16-demo-tf/blob/master/mnist_softmax_deep_conv_fp16_advanced.py, but I always encounter error ""Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is "
TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn." for the code "train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))", does anyone have idea for this? Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: What modifications did you make to the code? When I run it unmodified it works for me.

Comment: @ziedaniel1, thanks for remind, I compared my code with the original one, found that the implementation of computer_gradients is not the same, after change that to code as below, it works for me.                                                                                     def compute_gradients(tensor, var_list, loss_scale):
    grads = tf.gradients(tensor, var_list)
    return [grad/loss_scale if grad is not None else tf.zeros_like(var)
    for var, grad in zip(var_list, grads)]